# Store aggregate data in a table or a view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am doing a project in MS SQL server and i am currently concerned about the following case.

```
CartItems (table)
CartID      ItemID      Value
1           51          100
1           52          100
```

If I want to have a cart sum available as a fixed value and not to be calculated with SUM for each query do I

a) create table CartInfo with columns and fill data on each item change (trigger)

- CartID
- CartTotal

b) create view CartInfo with columns

- CartID
- CartTotal

Both solution are probably valid, but I am not sure based on what facts should I choose either a table or a view?

Comment: Trigger is very costly and slow.  If you want to do this logic you may want to have it calculate every night but only once.  Data will be up to 24 hours stale.  But it won't horribly slow down your database like your trigger idea does.  Problem is can you get away with day old data?

Comment: trigger on inset, update, delete will make db slow? old data? not sure about that...

Comment: Triggers are extremely costly particularly when used in this way.  Create a sample million row table.  Try it with and without the trigger.  Notice the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider an indexed view. That would materialize the total, providing the performance benefits of the table approach but without extra code to maintain it. The total will reflect new values in real time as underlying data are changed.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.CartItemSummary
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
AS
SELECT
      CartID 
    , SUM(Value) AS CartTotal
FROM dbo.CartItem
GROUP BY CartID;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX cdx_CartItemSummary ON dbo.CartItemSummary;
GO
```

Comment: Indexed view looks like an easy and clear solution here. What if I would change CartItem colum Value (name or type).. Would that break all depending view(s)? I oversimplyfied the problem, but would an additional table break dependency between table and one or many depending views? Futhermore ORMs dont cope well with views and navigation properties... at least EF

Comment: Indexed views require `SCHEMABINDING` and have associated restrictions. Before changing the table schema, you'll need to drop the view and recreate afterwards. If you are using Enterprise Edition, the optimizer can automatically use the view index even without referencing the view directly. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187864.aspx.

Comment: this answer is misleading, the indexed view doesn't actually store the aggregate value, if one does a select on the above view the execution plan shows index scan on the parent table on which the view was created, thereby showing that the aggregate operation is not actually stored rather just reexecuted and displayed

Comment: @yolob21, the view does materialize the aggregated data. However, if you query the view in SQL Server Standard Edition, it is necessary to specify the `WITH (NOEXPAND)` hint for the optimizer to consider the view index. The hint is not (always) needed with Enterprise Edition and, furthermore, the optimizer can consider using the view index when the underlying tables are accessed directly and not via the view.

Comment: Tried what you suggested, and the execution plan does show 100% cost on the view index, well something new to learn, but doesn't make sense why optimizer would then go for a scan on a parent table index instead of view index by default where data is already materialized

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend using a view here, since you don't have to handle an additional table and trigger which makes your solution less maintainable and more brittle. A view is exactly what you need: A (different) view on your existing data. You then don't need to be concerned about keeping the data in the second table "synchronized" (e. g. by using a trigger). The results of the view are always "up to date".

Comment: But it is exactly what he says he doesn't want?

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry, I didn't realize that. @Dario: Is there a good reason for not calculating the SUM in a view? (Performance, ..., ...)

Comment: @IngoB I dont avoid views, its just that having one or many views depending on a table can make life dificult if you want to change a scheme of a table. From my experience ORMs such as entity framework dont cope well with views (missing navigational properties)

Comment: If you have an orm for mundane stuff like this "customers-orders" scenario, it is the front end that builds the order, adds it up etc, not the back end db

Comment: Schema changes would mean you also need to change your second table and the trigger which is even more difficult to handle. But I understand your EF argument. Although there seem to be solutions to the navigation properties thingy.

Comment: @IngoB schema changes would probably mean trigger change, not necessarily second table change. but i guess i have to choose my poison

Comment: Well expressed! :D ;)

Answer (score -1):

Views don't contain information in the way a table does; they're simply a stored sql that is run every time you select from them. You may be referring to a materialised view, but it's not a SQL Server offering as far as I'm aware..

Comment: They're called indexed views in SQL Server and yes they are available.

Comment: No, indexed views and materialised views are very different. Indexed views are subject to considerably more restrictions and caveats in sql than mviews are in oracle, and have fewer real world use cases

Comment: I am talking only about MS SQL Server

Comment: That's why I said "views don't contain data" (because they don't) and "if you want something that contains data and has view in its name, create a materialised view, but not in sqlserver because it  doesn't have them". Essentially your question is like saying "I need to reach something on the top shelf but I can't. I have two choices: use a ladder, or flap my arms and fly up there" - you do not have two choices because one is not possible

Comment: Sounds like you're arguing semantics... An indexes view, SQL Server, does in fact materialize the data in it's clustered index (and any additional indexes).

Comment: the accepted answer is misleading, see my comment on the same